# Chromecast debugging not working

Tags: chromecast

I am having serious issues with the Chromecast debugger not working lately.

I am entering the correct IP, with port 9222. My app has been launched on the CC, it has worked in the past, and my CC is sending its serial number to Google, and it is whitelisted.

Anyone else that cant get the debugger to work 100%?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084550/chromecast-debugging-via-port-9222-stopped-working.
Clicking the shield icon on right did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and just figured this out.

With the changes to the Chromecast Remote Debugger, Chrome users have to copy/paste the chrome-devtools:// URL provided (as opposed to clicking the link) upon visiting receiver-ip:9222.

This is specified in the debugging documentation at Step 4 here:

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging

Comment: My issue is that I can't even access receiver-ip:9222. Also, when it does work, I don't even see a link starting with chrome-devtools://

Comment: Yes, I'm getting stuck on the 'enter the IP address of the device' part.  Can't locate my Chromecast's IP via the Chromecast setup app or any other means.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Update your firmware to the latest version >=31432

https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=537