# Chromecast debugging via port 9222 stopped working

Tags: debugging, chromecast

I've been using port 9222 to debug Chromecast receiver code for over a year. It stopped working today. I get

"You may have to select the shield icon in the address bar to establish a connection"

instead of the the debugging URL. There is no shield icon. This problem seems to be spreading slowly at our site. Everything is enabled for the Chrome browser.

I tried rebooting chromecast, rebooting PC, update Chrome, the Canary beta version, etc. No joy.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and filed a bug ticket here: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=537 -- Make sure to get in touch with support using the Chromecast extension for Google Chrome (desktop browser). It has a "Send feedback..." function. In your feedback make sure to mention bug ticket #537 and check the "Attach device logs" checkbox.

Answer (score 8):

Got the same issue.

I removed chromecast from whitelist and added it again.
Reset it again

After I get a page with a link to appengine (Remote Debugging (AppEngine)).
There you should allow to load scripts (press shield icon in the right of url path near favourite icon).

Enjoy debugging console  :)

Update:
Got one more issue - connection to reciever was refised until I check guest mode for reciever in chromecast developers console

Comment: Thanks. Looking for the shield icon after clicking Remote Debugging did the trick. I was looking for the shield icon in <device ip>:9222 page.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The Shield Icon is a Silvery Shield Icon to the Right of the URL.  Clicking on it will prompt you  to allow loading of unsafe scripts. Allow that and you will see the debug console come to life!

Comment: thanks! why they keep changing unimportant stuff and not making important changes, i don't know

Comment: @Mike, I checked the guest mode in console still no luck. 
http://egscr.com/7XQ4kf

This is what my browser show:http://egscr.com/Vv7VgH

Comment: @Max, Was chromecast app started when you try to debug? Note you need to be in the same network as chromecast.

Comment: @Mike It worked i have to add these two lines-->
cast.player.api.setLoggerLevel(cast.player.api.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);
cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);